# Convert .txt file to json using shell script or jq command

Tags: json, bash, shell, scripting, jq

I have the **data.txt** file containing below information:

```
611111|22|53|200003|ADD|234566|REMOVE|546768|647|Return|5647|746927|ADD|345677858|REMOVE|546768|64774|Return|5647|2134
611112|24|53|200043|ADD|234576|REMOVE|5467658|647|Return|5687|746927|ADD|445677858|REMOVE|546768|64774|Return|5647|2334
```

How can I convert into **.json** file like below :

**Output required :**

```
[
  {
    "ProductId": "611111",
    "PIDT": "22",
    "RPID": "53",
    "OfferId": "20003",
    "Product1": 
    [
      {
        "Action": "ADD",
        "ProductOfferId": "234566",
      },
      {
        "Action": "REMOVE",
       "ProductOfferId": "546768",
        "RemoveProduct1Instance": "647",
      },
      {
        "Action": "RETURN",
       "RemoveProduct1Instance": "5647",
        "ProductOfferId": "746927",
      }   
    ]
    "Product2": 
    [
      {
        "Action": "ADD",
        "NewComponentOfferId": "345677858",
      },
      {
        "Action": "REMOVE",
       "ComponentOfferId": "546768",
        "RemoveProduct2Instance": "64774",
      },
      {
        "Action": "RETURN",
       "RemoveProduct2Instance": "5647",
       "ProductOfferId": "2134"
      }   
    ]
  }
]
```

And like wise for every line.
Please suggest how we can obtain this using **jq command** or **shell scripting**?

Comment: What did you try? What is the error messages?

Comment: Does `ADD` always have exactly two and `REMOVE` and `RETURN` always have three components (including the `Action`)?
And are there always exactly two "Products"?

Comment: This may not be a good match for `jq`. (With `jq` one can easily convert from JSON to the string representation, but not necessarily the other way round.) You could, in theory, output JSON from Bash: (1) parse the input string into a Bash array with `|` as a field separator and then (2) use a big JSON template string with a few `%s` or `%d` placeholders and finally print it with `printf`. However, that would be **cumbersome**.

Comment: That^^^ said, why not just use JavaScript (e.g. Node or the like), use a `String`’s [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method, then construct an `Object` of the required structure and finally [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the result? That would be way less error-prone than Bash. Tip: Use a `class` to represent the product / offer structure and parse the `String` in its `constructor()`.

Comment: @ceving - please be assured that jq would be an excellent choice for this task, though it would be helpful if the requirements could be clarified. You might want to consider using `reduce`.

Comment: Where is the header of that csv file or is there none? Is the second line ignored and only the first line is converted and output or you just left it out?

Answer (score 0):

I am still missing certain constraints, such as

- Are there always exactly two Products or could there be also, say, three or even zero?
- Does a Product always have ADD, REMOVE and RETURN or could any of them be there twice or even missing?
- Are ADD, REMOVE and RETURN always in the same order? If not, how to distinguish between Products?

However, if all of them were static as provided in your example, I'd simply go with reading the raw input into an array of lines, split them further into arrays of values, then align them with a static ordered set of paths pointing into the output object, and build them setting the paths to those values accordingly.

```
jq -Rn '[inputs / "|" | [[
  
  ["ProductId"],["PIDT"],["RPID"],["OfferId"],
  (("Product1", "Product2") as $p |
    [$p, 0] + (["Action"], ["ProductOfferId"]),
    [$p, 1] + (["Action"], ["ProductOfferId"], ["RemoveProduct1Instance"]),
    [$p, 2] + (["Action"], ["RemoveProduct1Instance"], ["ProductOfferId"])
  )

],.] | transpose | reduce .[] as $k ({}; setpath($k[0];$k[1]))]' data.txt
```

Comment: Can you please explain this command?

Comment: Please provide what part needs more explanation. Having a cursory look:

`jq -Rn '[inputs]'` reads your raw input into an array of lines, `./"|"` splits a line into an array of values. Next, with `[…,.]` that array becomes the second element in a wrapper array with the first being the static array of paths (see my next comment). `transpose` converts the wrapper array into an array of arrays containing one element of each array wrapped, i.e. a path and a value. `reduce` iterates over those tuples and and constructs the object using `setpath`, backfeeding its output into the next iteration.

Comment: The static array of paths is constructed fairly straightforward. Bearing in mind that `setpath` requires the path to be an array of strings as keys of object values and numbers as indices of array elements, we can simply transcribe your desired output format one by one: The first four items are nothing but one-level deep objects. Then, we iterate over "Product1" and "Product2" in variable `$p`, essentially doubling the rest. That rest is three compositions of `$p`, an array index and another object key, which in turn is composed by iterating over the according alternatives.

Comment: Is there any option to write **if-else** condition in **jq** command? In case if there is only Product1 not Product2 how I can write the command?

Comment: Sure, `if … then … else … end` is possible in jq but, again, you are providing no useful constraints whatsoever. What would be the condition for the `if` part? Is it counting just one `ADD`? Is it 12 values instead of 20 in a row? That's why I was asking these questions beforehand. I can help you with coding your logic in jq but I can't figure out by myself what your logic is.

Comment: Let's take this example---> We have below rows in data.txt file -

**611111|22|53|200003|PRODUCT1|ADD|234566|REMOVE|546768|647|Return|5647|746927|PRODUCT2|ADD|345677858|REMOVE|546768|64774|Return|5647|2134
611451|2254|53|20000333|PRODUCT2|ADD|345677858|REMOVE|546768|64774|Return|5647|2134
61111671|2342|5343|44200003|PRODUCT2|ADD|345677858|REMOVE|546768|64774|Return|5647|2134|PRODUCT3|ADD|345677858|REMOVE|546768**

Comment: The first row having 2 Products Product1,Product2 w both ith ADD,REMOVE and RETURN sub-contraints.
The second row  having only Product2 with ADD,Remove and RETURN sub-constraints.
The third row is having product2 & Product 3 but product3 has only ADD and REMOVE sub-constraints.
Likewise there can be many rows with only one product or many and only one sub-constraints(ADD,REMOVE & RETURN) and many within this 3.
So I wan t the desired output like this below :

Comment: Likewise I want them in desired json output format.Please help me with the comand.

Comment: Please answer my questions. What would be the condition for `if` exactly? Could `ADD` be missing? And so on (see above). Plus some new ones: Is case relevant ("Return" vs "RETURN", "Product1" vs "PRODUCT1", you keep mixing them)? And most irritatingly: Why did you change your dataset (without notice)? You introduced another column which seems to have a product's name ("Product1"). Should this now distinguish Products? Then what is its format? Is it arbitrary so we must go for a column count, or is it always the string "Product" (case!) followed by a digit / a number? Please provide your logic.